# How to encrypt password while saving in database in Flutter-SQLite-Dart application?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, password-encryption, sqflite

I'm developing a mobile application using Flutter, Dart and SQLite. It is just a Login page validation kind of project where I need to encrypt the password and user's personal details while inserting in the database. At least I want the password to be encrypted. How is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: My simple concept would be: choose a crypto library, run the example, code to my needs. What have you done so far? For password hashing there are specialized libs like Argon2, BCrypt and PBKDF2 available on Flutter/Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used cryptographic hashing functions for Dart and it works fine for me.

The below code is what I used to hash the password.

```js
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; // for the utf8.encode method

void main() {
  var bytes = utf8.encode("password"); // data being hashed

  var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);

  print("Digest as bytes: ${digest.bytes}");
  print("Digest as hex string: $digest");
}
```

Comment: This is **hashing** and not **encryption** as you asked for

Comment: I'm new to flutter. Can you please elaborate on this concept? @MichaelFehr

Comment: You wrote about "*The below code is what I used to **encrypt** the password*" - your code is about hashing using a hash algorithm (here SHA-256). My comment is framework independent and has nothing to do with Flutter especially.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) plugin to encrypt strings.

you can do like this for Advanced Encryption Standard (AES):

```
      final plainText = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
      final key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');
      final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    
      final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    
      final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
      final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
    
      print(decrypted); // YOUR_PASSWORD
      print(encrypted.base64);// YOUR_ENCRYPTED_STRING
```